# Neo4j - web interface database info says "no node labels in database" when my nodes have labels

Tags: neo4j, label, nodes

I imported a graph database into neo4j where the node files had labels assigned in the headers, as the manual instructed. When I use the web interface, the database details tab says there are no labels in my database though. When I run queries involving node labels, everything seems to work. Has anybody else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the browser page. The displayed Node labels are not updated dynamically.